# Combine 2 sql rows to one after running query?

Tags: sql

I'm running the following query

```
SELECT fileslist.appid, fileslist.fileid, apps.name, fileslist.revision 
FROM fileslist INNER JOIN apps ON fileslist.appid = apps.appid 
WHERE fileslist.curf = '1'
```

I want it to look like this:

```
appid   fileid1   fileid2   name    revision
9        21        22     bobe       2
```

But I get this atm

```
appid   fileid  name    revision
9        21     bobe       2
9        22     bobe       2
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650774/sql-pivot-to-flatten-rows-into-columns?rq=1

Comment: Can any of this column have a different value ?

Comment: @RaphaelMarthe that is not what OP needs.

Comment: appid, name and revision will always be the same. fileid will vary

Comment: Then you have to decide what logic will you use when for the same appid, name and revision you have two different fileid. Do you want to select max, min or there is some other logic for that field...

Comment: No other logic. they will always be in that order. one will be smaller than the other..

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT fl.appid, MIN(fl.fileid) as fileid1, MAX(fl.fileid) as fileid2, 
       a.name, fl.revision 
FROM fileslist fl INNER JOIN
     apps a
     ON fl.appid = a.appid 
WHERE fl.curf = '1'
GROUP BY fl.appid, a.name, fl.revision;
```

Comment: wow sweet that worked! Could you explain the "MIN"/"MAX" and GROUP BY part if possible? Why does it need GROUP BY if you use MIN and MAX - what are MIN MAX actually doing?

Comment: @uaswpff . . . Look up the documentation for the database you are using.